# Implement Multiple Clients Checklists

Tags: php, html

I am developing a ticket management website, those who execute these tickets are the technicians, who do the rendering of customer services. monthly, yearly, or quarterly, technicians must check equipment so managers can know if equipment needs maintenance. each of these clients has a different amount of equipment, for example customer A has AC but customer B has no AC. 
the PMs are the measurement points that will be queried, in case Client A would be PM1 = AC. 
I have a table with all the PMs needed for all clients already implemented, I was thinking that I could associate the client name with the PMs that this client has, so I could generate tables automatically only queried which PMs from that client, I will submit this by post with $ .ajax ({}) 
My current problem is to notice how in this URL I can see which PMs are generated for this client. 
If I do a second query in this url by the client name to get the PMs, I could already know which fields, but would this slow down the whole process right? and even this is very practical at the level of code ....

my table to save the PM is like:

```
| Inspection_Time  | B_Value | C_Value | client | 
|------------------|---------|---------|--------| 
| dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm |      OK |      OK | A      |
| dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm |      OK |      OK | B      |
```

However, as I have several clients with different checklists, I'm not sure how to do the implementation, anyone have any idea how this should be done?

Currently I have several files with the configurations of each one checklist of each client (little practical)

Actual code exemple:

```
<?php 
    if($cliente == "001"){
      include("prev.tab/$cliente.php")
    }elseif($cliente == "002"){
      include("prev.tab/$cliente.php")
    }
    [...]
    }elseif($cliente == "500"){
      include("prev.tab/$cliente.php")
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**
code exemple from 'include("prev.tab/001.php")':

```html
<div class="table-wrap mt-40">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>P.M.</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>OBS</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ALARM EXT.</td>
                    <td>
                        <select  name="pm8"  class="form-control select2" size="1" required >
                        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                            <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
                            <option value="OK">OK</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="N/A"name="pm8obs">
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>other</td>
                    <td>
                        <select   class="form-control select2" size="1" required name="pm9">
                        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                            <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
                            <option value="OK">OK</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="N/A"name="pm9obs">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what is inside 001.php, 002.php, and so on? It may be possible to write just one 'cliente.php' file that uses the `$cliente` variable inside it. You should also consider using a database or some kind of data structure saved to a file if you intend to support hundreds of clients.

Comment: @Romen hello, i have made Edit to add some code exemple as you ask

Comment: Great, so are the tables in each of these files is specific to each client? Suppose you had a spreadsheet with a row for every client, could you use columns for each client row in the spreadsheet to represent which checklist items each client should see? If the answer is yes then you should consider storing this information about the clients in a database instead of inside the code itself. Even a spreadsheet or csv file could be used. It just depends on your requirements.

Comment: all tables are like that for each client(hard code for fast implementation) and yes is specific to each client, but now i whant to do that more dynamic...if i make a table using [client name , pm] how i create the tables and how do i save that information on sql

Comment: If you can represent the checklist for each client in a spreadsheet then it should be straightforward to create an SQL table based on that spreadsheet. I don't know what all of the possible items of your checklists could be so this is something you have to figure out. If there are a finite number of possible checklist items then a column with a YES/NO (boolean) value for each possible item could work. If the checklists could contain anything then you may need to use multiple tables to model those checklists. Trying to make it into a spreadsheet will tell you quicker than trying with SQL will.

Comment: @Romen i know that is ok on exel, but we whant that in web...can we make chat about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193048/discussion-between-noobdev-gbl-and-romen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty big question. My suggestion would be to use json. You can store that in various places the server directly under a client folder, in a database with the client id as a lookup, S3 buckets similar to a db, etc.

From there it would be a matter of what the format is. If each client can create their own questions and they are only selects then something as simple the below could be used and the index is where they appear in the code.

```
$json = '{
    "headers" : ["P.M", "status", "OBS"],
    "questions": [
        {
            "name" : "pm8",
            "text": "ALARM EXT",
            "options": [
                {
                    "display" : "N/A",
                    "value" : "N/A"
                },
                {
                    "display" : "OK",
                    "value" : "OK"
                },
                {
                    "display" : "NOK",
                    "value" : "NOK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "pm9",
            "text": "other",
            "options": [
                {
                    "display" : "N/A",
                    "value" : "N/A"
                },
                {
                    "display" : "OK",
                    "value" : "OK"
                },
                {
                    "display" : "NOK",
                    "value" : "NOK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';
```

With something like this you can then use php to access the data as an object and some simple loops:

```
<?php
//Access the data this is an example 
//I am not sure what you will use. 
//Just assuming a similar data structure is returned.
$json = your_storage($cliente);

//Change that JSON to an associative array
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
//Drop out of PHP to set up the html
?>
<div class="table-wrap mt-40">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    //In PHP again use what was retrieved earlier
                    foreach($data["headers"] as $header){
                        echo "<th>$header</th>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($data["questions"] as $question){
                echo '<tr>';    
                echo "<td>$question[text]</td>";
                echo '<td>';
                echo "<select  name='$question[name]'  class='form-control select2' size='1' d >";
                foreach($question["options"] as $option){
                    echo "<option value='$option[value]'>$option[display]</option>";
                }
                echo '</select>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="N/A"name="pm8obs">';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<tr>';            
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally I do not fall in and out of PHP like this. I use Twig to create my templates but that is a whole other setup I do not want to bring in here.

This is extensible too. If you want you could put a required flag to mark question as required. If there was more then selects then you can put a type and interrogate that in the php rendering.

Comment: tanks for the help, but is not what i'm looking for, pls see the update question EDIT2

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL To be honest I am not sure what the update is really trying to convey. Based on the comments and what was there it does seem that the new bit is in contradiction to what the original was. As I mentioned in this answer your question was already pretty big. This addition may be pushing it outside the scope of what SO can help with.